# HTMLParser python turn data into string?

Tags: python, html-parser

Hi I'm using this following python parser to read an html file

https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
    HTMLParser.__init__(self)
    self.inLink = False
    self.dataArray = []
    self.countLanguages = 0
    self.lasttag = None
    self.lastname = None
    self.lastvalue = None

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    self.inLink = False
    if tag == 'window':
        for name, value in attrs:
            if name == 'mode':
                #value = 0
                #print(value)
                self.countLanguages += 1
                self.inLink = True
                self.lasttag = tag

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag == "window":
        self.inlink = False

def handle_data(self, data):
    self.data = data
    #print(self.data)
    print data
    if data.strip():
        self.inlink = False
        #print data

  parser = MyHTMLParser()
  input_file = open('xmlfile.xml')
  feed_data = input_file.read().strip()
  feed_data = parser.feed(feed_data)
  print(feed_data.data)
  input_file.close()
```

However, I cant seem to find a way to turn the data returned from html parser into a string.

I'm basically modyfing an attribute using html parser, then I want to turn the data into a string - any idea how to do that?

I've tried adding a "self.data" to the "handle_data" function, but I cant seem to print any data coming back. Is there a way to just print everything held in the parser?

Comment: Can you Share your Code with us?

Comment: I suggest you using  Scrapy http://scrapy.org/

Comment: Im afraid scapy wont work for me I can only use standard python installed modules

Comment: Can you share `xmlfile.xml`?

Comment: I'm asking how to turn the resulting object from htmlparser into a string (for usage afterwards) - why would the shared xml help? it shouldnt matter

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that might suit your needs for this specific question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import urllib.request 
url = "http://www.google.com"


with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read().decode('utf-8')

print (html)
```

Comment: Is there a way to traverse through the tags and modify the html? Would I use htmlparser to do this?

Comment: If you want to acces certain 'nodes' of the HTML, and modify the data/content in there, use an XML/HTML parser, yes.

Comment: That is the question - how to parse the data and turn the data back into a string.

Comment: I tried answering your "Is there a way to just print everything held in the parser?" question. Parsing XML in Python is well documented. Here is an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm

Comment: Yes Nubuntu, unfortunately I cannot use a normal xml parser, because my document is not well formed :/

Comment: You could of course use the Dark Side of the Force, and use a regular expression. (Don't do it!) (Example: https://github.com/studio-hd/python-scripts/blob/master/useful/hetweernu.py)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code, I found that the `feed()` function doesn't return anything.

> ```
> def feed(self, data):
>     r"""Feed data to the parser.
>
>     Call this as often as you want, with as little or as much text
>     as you want (may include '\n').
>     """
>     self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
>     self.goahead(0)
> ```

So we can rewrite it as:

```
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.Myrawdata = ""

    def feed(self, data):
        self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
        self.Myrawdata = self.Myrawdata + data
        self.goahead(0)

    # your code...

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<div><style type="text/css">#python { color: green }</style></div>')
print "Rawdata:", parser.Myrawdata
```

The reason why not use `self.rawdata` is that it will be empty when `feed()` end.

Comment: This looks interesting but when I change the data inside the tag using handle_start_tag - those changes arent reflect in the Myrawdata variable - Im guessing this is because this is the raw unchanged data?? Any way to get the changed data?

Comment: So you need a manageable data structure(a tree maybe) to save all what handle functions get, and an algorithm to rebuild it. That's a hard way, or **BeautifulSoup** is more suitable for this. Simply replacing some sub-strings in `Myrawdata` is an easy way but unreliable.